# How to set up JWT-Auth with Laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel, authentication, jwt

Pretty new to laravel and I'm creating backend API for Angularjs application with it, and now I'm stuck at the authentication part.

I decided to go for https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth to handle the authentication and tokens.

Problem is, the wiki of  JWT-Auth doesn't tell me anything about how to setup user database. It only tells me that I can autheticate like this

```
    $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)
```

But of course it won't work before it has some place to look up for those credentials.

How do I manage to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5 comes with User model already, if you have migrated the User table to your database (set database credentials in the `.env` file in your project root) using `php artisan migrate`, then it's a simple matter of creating a user.

The migration files for the User model should already be included too.

Then you can create a user by making a database seed, or simply execute:

```
User::create(
     [
         'name' => 'you', 
         'email' => 'you@you.com', 
         'password' => Hash::make('secret')
     ]
);
```

You can then login using JWTAuth with the credentials in an array like

```
['email' => 'you@you.com', 'password' => 'secret']
```

Depending on where you call the `User::create()`, you might have to include

```
use App\User;
```

in the top of your Controller, where App is your app's namepace. `App` is the default namespace, but you can easily change this to whatever you want , it is entirely optional and you don't have to do this. Just adding this, in case you changed it.

Edit: Perhaps this external [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) on scotch.io might help you more in the long run.

Comment: Any idea how to change the authentication from email&password pair to something else like username&secret.

Comment: Check here: http://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#authenticating-users Not sure about the password, or if it will always check the 2nd argument against a hash. Haven't tested that.

Comment: I can't find an example there for this. It says that "email isn't required", but no example how to change it to anything else. :(

Comment: I think it's a matter of changing if `Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]) ` to `Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])` in your code, where you Auth the user (or you get the gist, just change email to username). From docs: `The password value will be hashed. The other values in the array will be used to find the user in your database table.`. I don't think it's possible to change the password field without making some more radical changes. Best open a new question for that on SO.

Comment: Any idea on how to use a different model in the auth process? I use the default User entity for the app admin, and created other entity with different db table for customers which will use the app via API.